# laravel 6 route returing 404 not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-storage

While Passing variable in URL and route returning only 404, not found#.
Did some google and found some result and tried some methods on youtube its also not working. Totally Beginner to laravel

room.blade.php

```
//In roomdetail->id its passing the value of room
<a href="/detail/{{$roomdetail->id}}" class="btn btn-primary ">Detail</a>
```

web.php

```
//The route which I am using

Route::get('/detail/{$id}', 'DetailController@show')->name('detail.show');
```

DetailController.php

```
public function show($id)
    {
        dd($id);
    }
}
```

In DD I want to get the Id so I can fetch data from the database it's showing only 404

Answer (score 3):

Your route is wrong you are using `$` in a param which is wrong instead of `{$id}` in route it should be `{id}`

change this

```
Route::get('/detail/{$id}', 'DetailController@show')->name('detail.show');
```

To

```
Route::get('/detail/{id}', 'DetailController@show')->name('detail.show');
```

and a quick tip as you are using named route then it would be better if you use `route` method to pass variable to route in view

So in your view change this:

```
<a href="/detail/{{$roomdetail->id}}" class="btn btn-primary ">Detail</a>
```

To

```
<a href="{{ route('detail.show', $roomdetail->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary ">Detail</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: @SamirParuthi happy to help. Mark it as accepted answer if it helped you.

Comment: salman can i need your email id to connect with you as i am a learner and will need your help in many cases?

Comment: @SamirParuthi you can see my profile for this and also you have not mark my answer as accepted kindly do that first. Thanks

Comment: I have only 8 reputations and to mark an answer correct user need 15 reputation

Comment: i faced quite a similar problem today and this solved my problem.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Remove '/' from URL or pass route

```
<a href="detail/{{$roomdetail->id}}" class="btn btn-primary ">Detail</a>
```

**OR**

```
<a href="{{ route('detail.show','id'=>[$roomdetail->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary ">Detail</a>
```

or change your route as `{id}` instead of `{$id}`

it should be `Route::get('/detail/{id}', 'DetailController@show')->name('detail.show');`